# Disable automatic Dark Mode in Samsung Internet

Tags: browser, darkmode, samsung-internet

I have a problem where Samsung Internet tries to render my page in Dark mode, even though it already has one. This causes the text to be black on a dark gray background, which is unusable. You can disable that in the settings of Samsung Internet, but that is not a good solution, as it requires user action.

Is there a way to indicate to the browser, that the website already has a dark mode and doesn't need to be adjusted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Samsung Internet forces dark mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66094087/samsung-internet-forces-dark-mode)